# How to handle date fields in a non-model Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activemodel

I am creating a non-model object that will be used with a Rails form builder by using `ActiveModel`. This is a Rails 3 project. Here's an example of what I have so far:

```
class SalesReport
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :promotion_code, :start_date, :end_date

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

I happen to be using HAML and simple_form, but that's not important. Ultimately, I'm just using standard Rails date select fields:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @report], as: :report, url: admin_reports_path do |f|
  = f.input :promotion_code, label: 'Promo Code'
  = f.input :start_date, as: :date
  = f.input :end_date, as: :date
  = f.button :submit
```

Rails splits up the date fields into individual fields, so when the form is submitted, there are actually 3 date fields that are submitted:

```
{
  "report" => {
    "start_date(1i)" => "2014",
    "start_date(2i)" => "4",
    "start_date(3i)" => "1"
  }
}
```

In my `SalesReport` object, I'm assigning the params to my `attr` methods, but I'm getting an error that I don't have a `start_date(1i)=` method, which I obviously haven't defined. Ultimately, I'd like to end up with a `Date` object that I can use instead of 3 separate fields.

How should I handle these date fields in my non-model object?

Answer (score 4):

In your initialization you could manually assign the values from attributes to the class methods and down below override you `start_date` and `end_date` setter methods.

```
class SalesReport
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :promotion_code, :start_date, :end_date

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @promotion_code = attributes['promotion_code']
    year = attributes['start_date(1i)']
    month = attributes['start_date(2i)']
    day = attributes['start_date(3i)']
    self.start_date = [year, month, day]
  end

  def start_date=(value)
    if value.is_a?(Array)
      @start_date = Date.new(value[0].to_i, value[1].to_i, value[2].to_i)
    else
      @start_date = value
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

This should allow you to give the setter a `Date` instance or an `Array` with the separate date elements and the setter will assign the correct date to `@start_date`.
Just do the same for `@end_date`.

Hope this can help you.