# Handle date in simpleform with activemodel in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activemodel

I have a ActiveModel in my model like below:

```
class PromotionCodesGenerator
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :no_of_codes,:start_date,:end_date
end
```

And the view like below

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for ([:admin, @promotion_codes_generator]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :start_date, as: :date, default: Time.zone.now, wrapper_tag: :p %>
      <%= f.input :end_date, as: :date, default: Time.zone.now + 1.month, wrapper_tag: :p %>
<% end %>
```

When the form is submitted the param looks like this

```
{"no_of_codes"=>"12", "start_date(1i)"=>"2016", "start_date(2i)"=>"12", "start_date(3i)"=>"15", "end_date(1i)"=>"2017", "end_date(2i)"=>"1", "end_date(3i)"=>"15"}
```

And of course this gives me error

```
undefined method `start_date(1i)='
```

when im trying to initiate the model in my controller.

```
@promotion_codes_generator = PromotionCodesGenerator.new(promotion_codes_generator_params)
```

So how should i handle the dates properly?

Comment: don't use the date helpers. go with javascript datepickers and a simple text input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798691/how-to-handle-date-fields-in-a-non-model-rails-form

Comment: If any of these solutions worked for you, please select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `as: :date` with `as: :string`

```
<%= f.input :start_date, as: :string, default: Time.zone.now, wrapper_tag: :p %>
<%= f.input :end_date, as: :string, default: Time.zone.now + 1.month, wrapper_tag: :p %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem called [`multiparameter_attributes_handler`](https://github.com/reggieb/multiparameter_attributes_handler). If you apply it to `params` it will create entries for `end_date` and `start_date` with date objects constructed from the form element submissions. That will allow you to keep the rails helper date form drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery date-pickers in conjunction with simple form custom inputs. Doing it this way is especially helpful if you want to display American formatted time (mm/dd/yyyy), but submit the fields in the rails format (yyyy-mm-dd) through the alt_field. If you want to do this, first make sure you have the jquery-rails gem installed.

Create the custom simple form input for dates in app/inputs/datepicker_input.rb :

```
class DatepickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
   def input(wrapper_options)
      merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)
      class_name = object.class.name.underscore + "_"
      "#{@builder.text_field(attribute_name, merged_input_options)}".html_safe +
      "#{@builder.hidden_field(attribute_name, { id: class_name + attribute_name.to_s + '-alt'}) }".html_safe
   end
end
```

This custom input creates a text field to display the formatted date to the user, and a hidden field to be submitted in place of the the displayed text field. The hidden field is given and id of the class_name + attribute_name + -alt. This id will be used in the JQuery date-picker initialization to specify the hidden field.

In your form simply change "as: :date" to "as: :datepicker":

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for ([:admin, @promotion_codes_generator]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :start_date, as: :datepicker, default: Time.zone.now, wrapper_tag: :p %>
      <%= f.input :end_date, as: :datepicker, default: Time.zone.now + 1.month, wrapper_tag: :p %>
<% end %>
```

In your javascript:

```
$("#admin_start_date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
  altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  altField: $("#admin_start_date-alt")
});

$("#admin_end_date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
  altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  altField: $("#admin_end_date-alt")
});
```

The altField with a format of "yy-mm-dd" will be submitted in place of the displayed "mm/dd/yy" field. In your controller simply permit you the params start_date and end_date inside of you object as you already do.